# Colocar campo que se pueda dejar en blanco o no

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo un par de campos en mysql que quiero que se queden en blanco pero me salta el error de que tengo que ingresarlos y el problema es que no siempre se van a quedar en blanco

este es el insert de los datos

```
$Nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["Nombre"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $equipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["equipo"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $ciudad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["ciudad"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $departamento = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["departamento"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $Cargo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["Cargo"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $cantidad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cantidad"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $justificacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["justificacion"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $Cargo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["Cargo"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $agregado=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $entregado=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["entregado"],ENT_QUOTES)));
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE Nombre = '" . $Nombre . "' OR Nombre = '" . $Nombre . "';";
            $query_check_Nombre = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                $sql = "INSERT INTO funcionarios (Nombre, Cargo, equipo, ciudad, departamento, cantidad, justificacion, agregado, entregado)
                        VALUES('".$Nombre."','".$Cargo."','" .$equipo. "','" .$ciudad. "','" .$departamento. "','" .$cantidad. "','" .$justificacion. "', '" .$agregado . "', '" .$entregado ."' );";
                $query_new_prestamo_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                // if user has been added successfully
                if ($query_new_prestamo_insert) {
                    $messages[] = "La cuenta ha sido creada con éxito.";
                } else {
                    $errors[] = "Lo sentimos , el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
                }
            }
```

estos son los campos en el modal donde los agrego

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Nombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombres</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="equipo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Equipo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="equipo" name="equipo" placeholder="Equipo" required>
    </div>
     </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cantidad" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cantidad</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholder="cantidad" required>
    </div>
     </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="justificacion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Justificacion</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="justificacion" name="justificacion" placeholder="justificacion">
    </div>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group">
    <label for="departamento" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Departamento</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="departamento" name="departamento" placeholder="Departamento" required>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Cargo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cargo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cargo" name="Cargo" placeholder="Cargo" required>
    </div>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ciudad" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ciudad</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" placeholder="ciudad" required>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="agregado" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Agregado</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="agregado" name="agregado" placeholder="Fecha de agregada la solicitud">
    </div>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="entregado" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Entregado</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="entregado" name="entregado" placeholder="Fecha de entrega del equipo">
    </div>
     </div>
```

y los campos que quiero que quiero que queden libres
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les quite el required del modal pero en el insert de los datos me da este error `$errors[] = "Lo sentimos , el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";`

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar lo que quisiste decir aquí: *Tengo un par de campos en mysql que quiero que se queden en blanco pero me salta el error de que tengo que ingresarlos y el problema es que no siempre se van a quedar en blanco...*?

Comment: ¿Has probado a imprimir la consulta e insertarla directamente en el `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Probaste a sacar un echo de las variables y de $sql antes de mysqli_query() como lo hemos hecho anteriormente ?

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta, ¿el problema es que quieres insertar valores vacios o que no quieres que el usuario ingrese esos datos por el formulario?

Comment: que errror te marca exactamente?

Comment: aver los campos que dije los de agregado y justificacion aveces se van a dejar en blanco y aveces no, PD: quiero insertar valores vacios, el error lo digo en la pregunta

Comment: El problema entonces es que debes cambiar el predeterminado de la estructura de la base de datos a _ninguno_ (_none_ en ingles), ya que cuando le dices que predeterminado sea _NULL_, la BBDD espera recibir un valor, ya sea NULL o cualquier otro, no una cadena vacía. Si no quieres alterar tu BBDD en la respuesta de abajo ya te ha contestado como dar el valor NULL en php.

Comment: ok ya la marque como respuesta muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se que campos quieras que queden en blanco pero si te refieres a dejarlos pasar si estan vacios algunos te pongo el codigo de como lo hago yo.

```
if(isset($datos["calle"]))
            $calle = $this->conexion -> real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($datos["calle"]))));
        else
            $calle = NULL;
```

aqui esta

```
if(isset($_POST["justificacion"]))
$justificacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["justificacion"],ENT_QUOTES)));
else
$justificacion =NULL;
```

Comment: quiero el que dice entregado y justificacion

Comment: tienes que usar if y un isset para saber si existe si no le asignas NULL saludos

Comment: vale muchas gracias me sirvio

Comment: una mini pregunta como hago para el date porque me da error

Comment: que error te arroja?

Comment: el mismo que esta en la pregunta me dio error con el "entregado"

Comment: es lo mismo kevin cambia justificacion por el nombre del entregado y lo guardas en la variable entregado, si no entiendes lo que se esta haciendo debes repasar tu codigo o de nada sirve que te de la respuesta

Comment: si entiendo ya lo hice pero no me dio  ` if(isset($_POST["entregado"]))
               $entregado = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["entregado"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            else
                $entregado =NULL;`

Comment: else
$justificacion ='0000-00-00';

Comment: si tu campo es date con eso te debe funcionar

Comment: si es date pero no funciono

Comment: haz un var_dump($consulta) y dime que te arroja

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\inventario\ajax\nuevo_prestamo.php:52:null

Comment: jaja no!!!  haz var_dump($query_check_Nombre);   despues de esta linea $query_check_Nombre = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\inventario\ajax\nuevo_prestamo.php:61:
object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => int 0
  public 'field_count' => int 10
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => int 3
  public 'type' => int 0

Answer (score 0):

Revisa lo siguiente:

1-Los campos del sql deben poder permitir NULL.
2-Comprueba con un isset las variables que reciben POST. De modo tal que si no estan instanciadas, las hagas NULL.